# Moveit_servo with ur_modern_driver

Tags: moveit, robotic-arm, control, universal-robot, visual-servoing

I have been working on a UR10 (older version, thus using **ur_modern_driver**) for pick and place movements.

However for a specific case I want to change to **smooth servoing towards an object based on relative x,y,z position** of the object detected by camera and a distance sensor. I have been considering doing it without moveit using direct velocity commands (e.g. for movement in z-direction `speedl_cmd = "speedl([0,0," + std::to_string(z_robot_vel) + ",0,0,0], 0.5, 0.1)";`) in a custom control loop but would like if the implementation could be in moveit with the functionalities that comes with this and as the rest of the code is.

In the [move_it Realtime Arm Servoing tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com) it is being mentioned that it has been "tested heavily" on UR using ur_modern_driver but I cannot find any examples or description on how anywhere.

I have been trying to modify the implementation I have but without luck.
Thus I would like to hear if anyone have had luck with this and if I could have a look on your setup and environment.

Many thanks in advance.